# Inconsistent line spacing

Tags: fontsize, paragraphs, line-spacing

If I type something like this:

```
{\itshape\LARGE
  Dunt venim dolorerosto do odit
  ametum vulla conum dolore
  conulput in vero od el
  Dunt venim dolorerosto do odit
  ametum vulla conum dolore
  conulput in vero od el
}
```

it results in a block of 4 lines with narrow spacing between the 1st and 2nd line and between the 3rd and 4th line. Line spacing between the 2nd and 3rd line is normal.

I can't fully explaing it to myself so I am looking for a short description for this behaviour. I know for example that with a `\par` at the end of the text (inside the group), the calculation would correct. But I have no idea why...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Make sure to end the paragraph (using `\par`, for example) before leaving the group; compare:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

% wrong    
{\itshape\LARGE
  Dunt venim dolorerosto do odit
  ametum vulla conum dolore
  conulput in vero od el
  Dunt venim dolorerosto do odit
  ametum vulla conum dolore
  conulput in vero od el
}

% right    
{\itshape\LARGE
  Dunt venim dolorerosto do odit
  ametum vulla conum dolore
  conulput in vero od el
  Dunt venim dolorerosto do odit
  ametum vulla conum dolore
  conulput in vero od el\par
}

\end{document}
```

The reason why a `\par` (or some form of paragraph ending) is needed is that `\LARGE` (and the other font size changing commands) changes the the value for `\baselineskip` and `\par` is the command that ends the paragraph and applies the right `\baselineskip`.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some reason as to why the `\par` was necessary.

Comment: Yes, because I've already mentioned the \par-solution ;)

Comment: The explanation about the necessity of `\par` made the difference. +1