# Tcolorbox sidebyside right side "top align" problem

Tags: vertical-alignment, tcolorbox

When a tcolorbox is inside the right side of a sidebyside tcolorbox, it is vertically centered. Using `\vfill` or `align = top` doesn't put the tcolorbox at the top of the right side. The space between the tcolorbox and the upper part of the right side is variable. Is there a way to put the tcolorbox at the right side top?

Tcolorboxes in the right side: centered.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[skins,listings,breakable,listingsutf8,theorems,hooks,fitting]{tcolorbox}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title= First Outer Box,sidebyside]
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
\tcblower
Variable vertical space
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=First Box Right Side]
Inside 1st box
First Outer Box
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=Second Box Right Side]
Inside 2nd box
First Outer Box
\end{tcolorbox} 

\end{tcolorbox} % first outer box

\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title= Second Outer Box,sidebyside]
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
\tcblower
Variable vertical space.
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=First Box Right Side]
Inside 1st box
Second Outer Box
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=Second Box Right Side]
Inside 2nd box
Second Outer Box
\end{tcolorbox} 
\end{tcolorbox} % first outer box
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `sidebyside align` key (possible values are `top`, `bottom` and, the default, `center`):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[skins,listings,breakable,listingsutf8,theorems,hooks,fitting]{tcolorbox}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title= First Outer Box,sidebyside,sidebyside align=top]
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
\tcblower
Variable vertical space
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=First Box Right Side]
Inside 1st box
First Outer Box
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=Second Box Right Side]
Inside 2nd box
First Outer Box
\end{tcolorbox} 

\end{tcolorbox} % first outer box

\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title= Second Outer Box,sidebyside,sidebyside align=top]
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
Left side of Outer Box\\
\tcblower
Variable vertical space.
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=First Box Right Side]
Inside 1st box
Second Outer Box
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=Second Box Right Side]
Inside 2nd box
Second Outer Box
\end{tcolorbox} 
\end{tcolorbox} % first outer box
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Therefore, "sidebyside align=top" doesn't work alone has to be paired with "sidebyside". Thanks !

Comment: Can we increase the left column width and decrease the right column width?

Comment: @SayOL: the outer box may specify the parameters `lefthand width` and `righthand width` which control the column width.

Comment: @FK82 Thank for your suggestion! Actually, I posted a question a few weeks ago and an acceptable solution was already given :)

Comment: @SayOL Great! Just wanted to add this since your question was left unanswered and I came across the same problem.

Comment: just in case someone tries to get this working with an `\includegraphics[]{}` on one of the sides... don't forget the `\vspace{0ex}`   (see here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500284/172810)