# How to align text at right top besides of an image?

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I've tried for hours to find a solution for this fairly simple layout. The closest I've got is:

```
\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{res/server.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.75\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
        asdasd\\
        asdasdasdasdasddsa
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

.. which produces something like:
[image: example]

How to move the text up to the top line?

I've seen many solutions with tables and boxes. Is there a simple way to do it with `minipage`?

## With `[t]` alignment of the minipage

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{res/server.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.75\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
        some text\\
        some more text
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

[image: more]

## With `\vspace{0pt}`

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{.25\textwidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{res/server.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.75\textwidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \begin{flushright}
        some text\\
        some more text
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

[image: another]

Comment: More specifically the comment below the first answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81955/align-text-in-minipage-at-same-height#comment1206175_81956

Comment: I also don't get the desired result with `[t]` or `fbox`. I've seen this question when I did my research. I can add a negative `vspace` to get it working, but it's an ugly solution :(

Comment: Did you include `\vspace{0pt}`? For me `\begin{minipage}[t]{.25\textwidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{res/server.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.75\textwidth}
 \vspace{0pt}
    \begin{flushright}
        asdasd\\
        asdasdasdasdasddsa
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}` works correctly.

Comment: Admittedly this is still a bit hacky, but you don't have to find the correct amount of negative vspace with trial and error, you just have to trick the `minipage`s by providing equally high contents to align to.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you for answering. Unfortunately also with `\vspace{0pt}` something odd happens.

Comment: Maybe your image has some white space at the top?

Comment: If not, then you have to provide a more complete example, with a documentclass, begin and end document, and possibly some `\usepackage` statements, that allow to reproduce the problem. When you make an MWE use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`, that allows to compile the document when the image file is not available.

Comment: Indeed.. some options I've set to `graphicx` caused this problem. Marijn, thank you so much!

Comment: You can try this code, with `tabularx`: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.5\hsize\arraybackslash}X@{}}%
       \raisebox{-\dimexpr\height + \baselineskip}{ \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{res/server.jpg}} & \begin{flushright}
            asdasd\\
            asdasdasdasdasddsa
        \end{flushright}
    \end{tabularx}`