# Top-align tikz next to a tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, minipage

I'd like to align a tabular next to a tikz graphic in such way that both tabular and the graphic would start on the top of the page. However, even after adding the `[t]` option, the tabular, which is shorter than the grapic, ends up aligned to the bottom of the graphic.

Here's a minimal example

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            A & B \\
            \hline
            1 & 2 \\
            3 & 4 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) circle (3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
    
    % The rest of the document

\end{document}
```

The result ends up looking like this
[image: E]

How can I move the tabular to the top of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional `\vspace{0pt}` at the top of each minipage should do.

Reference: Comments to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81956/234654) and [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500284/234654).

> What did work is to be sure to set the `[t]` position indicator for each minipage, and then to specify `\vspace{0pt}` at the top of each minipage. Then the resulting minipages are all aligned at the top of each other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \noindent % <- for overfull box
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
        \vspace{0pt} % <-- add this
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            A & B \\
            \hline
            1 & 2 \\
            3 & 4 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
        \vspace{0pt} % <-- add this
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) circle (3);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{minipage}
    
    % The rest of the document

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]