# Unbalanced distribution

Tags: spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inconsistent line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36454/inconsistent-line-spacing)

Why is this text distribution unbalanced? As you can see, there is more space between the first line and the second, than between the second and the third.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}
  \hbox{}\vfill
  {
    \parindent=0pt
    \LARGE\scshape

    First Sentence\\

    Second Sentence\  
    Third Sentence\\
  }
  \vfill
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need ``\\``, but you *do* need an empty line before the closing brace. Instead of `\hbox{}\vfill` prefer `\vspace*{\fill}`

Comment: Thanks. That works. Could you expand your comment to a full answer, please?

Comment: @egreg Why is `\vspace*{\fill}` preferable to `\hbox{}\vfill`?