# Awkward line spacing with \LARGE font size

Tags: fontsize, paragraphs, line-spacing

I'm confused about the look of my rendered output. It looks strange. I'm not doing anything special, but it looks like there is not enough vspace between the lines? The letters are almost touching.

I googled a lot but could not find anything about this.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\vspace{50mm}
{\LARGE\textbf{Development of Self-Cleaning Clothes for Everyone that is Busy All The Time}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Line spacing is decided by the font size active at the end of a paragraph. Put a `\par` before the closing brace of the `\LARGE` command: `... time}\par}`

Comment: also see this question: [Inconsistent line spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36459/579)

Answer (score 8):

You enclose the text to be typeset in `\LARGE`  in a group, but don't end it with a paragraph (`\par` or a blank line before the closing brace), so the line spacing is still that of `\normalsize`.

Solution: Either add `\par`/a blank line or -- as the `center` environment already provides a group and adds `\par` at its end -- remove the additional group.