# Using mathpazo so I can set arbitrary font sizes, but the <line space> attribute is inherited solely from \normalsize

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing, mathpazo

I'm using the mathpazo package so I can set arbitrarily large font sizes for a poster.  I set my font sizes in the preamble as such:

```
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{36pt}{48pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\large}{\fontsize{64pt}{100pt}\selectfont}
```

But when I use `\large`, the line space is `48pt` not `100pt` as it should be (note that `100pt` is not the actual value I want on my poster, this is just for demonstration purposes here).

If I change the line space value of `\normalsize` to `100pt`, then when I use `\large` the line space is `100pt`.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm,left=2cm]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\linespread{1}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{36pt}{48pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\large}{\fontsize{64pt}{100pt}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

test 1 test 2 test 3 test 4 test 5 test 6 test 7 test 8 test 9

{\large test 1 test 2 test 3 test 4 test 5 test 6 test 7 test 8 test 9}

\end{document}
```

Resulting document:

[image: output document]

But if I use:

```
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{36pt}{100pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\large}{\fontsize{64pt}{100pt}\selectfont}
```

I get:

[image: output document]

Hmmm...

Comment: Your test of `\large` finishes before the paragraph ends.  Add `\par` before the final brace.

Comment: @AndrewSwann - You beat me to this answer/comment by about two seconds...

Comment: Note that it makes no sense to say you are loading `mathpazo` (in particular) so you can use arbitrary sized fonts. You just need to make sure you are using scalable fonts. But that's recommended in almost all cases anyway.

Comment: potential duplicate: [Inconsistent line spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36454/579)