# How to justify only the first column of this user-defined tabular environment **while using ragged2e**? [UPDATED]

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, justification

I'm currently updating my CV using a very cool template I found on the Internet quite a long time ago (a user-defined CV class + the template itself). During these years, I've been more or less able to tweak both the `.cls` and the `.tex` files according to my needs, but now I'm facing a challenge I cannot solve on my own. At some point in the `.cls`, a new environment called `entrylist` is defined.

Consider now the MWE below. With the `entrylist` environment as it is defined (notice that it's just a somewhat fancy tabular enviornment), the content of the first column is not justified (see output below). I have tried many things to justify the content of the first column, but I haven't succeeded so far. In different words, the goal is to get "short name or date" and "much much longer name or date" both justified. Thus, **does anyone how to justify only the content of the first column?**

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{7.00cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}


\begin{document}

  \begin{entrylist}

  \vspace{5pt}
  \entry
    {Short name or date}
    {WHATEVER}
    {Whatever}
    {Whatever}

  \vspace{5pt}
  \entry
    {much much longer name or date}
    {WHATEVER}
    {Whatever}
    {Whatever}

\end{entrylist}


\end{document}
```

[image: current output]

PS: feel free either to comment on the warnings or to ignore them -I'll be dealing with them as soon as possible.

Thank you all for your time and effort!

**EDIT!** After David Carlisle's answer, I noticed that I need any possible solution to be compatible with the package `ragged2e`. In different words, I still need to get that column justified while the rest of the document is affected by `[document]ragged2e`. **Is this possible?** (maybe using the 
`array` package...?)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm afraid I'm not fully getting your comment. I have just been playing with `\setlength\parfillskip{0pt}` and I saw no major change in the desired direction. As you mention, what I want is to over-stretch the short sentence: namely, I want the "short name or date" to be as long as "much much longer name or date", if possible.

Comment: Okai: I now get that it's using the standard justification. What I don't yet get is how to over-stretch what I need... What do you exactly mean by "then set parfillskip to 0pt inside the parbox"? I'm sorry for being so slow.

Comment: no you were not slow, you are not using a parbox in that column, I misread, I'll post in a bt

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have modified my question requiring, if possible, any solution to be compatible with `\RequirePackage[document]{ragged2e}`. Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated. PS: I'm sorry for not including this requirement in my initial question --my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You need to remove the `\hfil` glue added by the `l` column specification so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \spaceskip0pt\xspaceskip0pt % for ragged2e document settting
  #1\hspace*{0pt plus -1fil}\mbox{}&\parbox[t]{7.00cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize #3\par}%no!\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}


\begin{document}

  \begin{entrylist}

  \vspace{5pt}
  \entry
    {Short name or date}
    {WHATEVER}
    {Whatever}
    {Whatever}

  \vspace{5pt}
  \entry
    {much much longer name or date}
    {WHATEVER}
    {Whatever}
    {Whatever}

\end{entrylist}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why did you comment "no!" after `{\footnotesize #3\par}`?

Comment: @Héctor ending a font size without a para causes issues with line spacing, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36459/1090 (although actually you don't have a paragraph before the size change either so perhaps you do want small text on a normal baseline (in which case ignore my comment:-)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Although your answer works fine in the MWE, it does not work when I embed it into the .cls file, which is where I need it. Commenting `\RequirePackage[document]{ragged2e}` in the `.cls` file made it work. But then, the entire document is justified, which is something I don't want. Can I get your (or any other) solution to work while using `\RequirePackage[document]{ragged2e}`?

Comment: @Héctor I added a line for `\RequirePackage[document]{ragged2e}`

Comment: Perfect, that made it work! Thank you very much. ^^