# How to justify only the first column of a user-defined tabular environment?

Tags: tables, lists

Some time ago, I posted a question asking [**how to justify only the first column of [a] user-defined tabular environment**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473760/how-to-justify-only-the-first-column-of-this-user-defined-tabular-environment). Although David Carlisle provided a satisfactory answer, his answer only works when the column in question contains at least two or more words. This is so because the answer he provided justifies the text by adjusting the intra-word space. I now need a solution to my problem that works for whenever there is a single word too. As in my original question, the answer must be compatible with `ragged2e`.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \spaceskip0pt\xspaceskip0pt % for ragged2e document settting
  #1\hspace*{0pt plus -1fil}\mbox{}&\parbox[t]{10.00cm}{\strut%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize #3\par}%no!\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}

\begin{document}

  \begin{entrylist}

   \entry
    {Office addr}
    {A very fancy building in a very fancy place}
    {}
    {}

   \entry
    {Web addr}
    {www.somename.com}
    {}
    {}

  \entry
    {Pers email}
    {somename a aaa}
    {}
    {}

  \entry
    {Work email}
    {veryfancyname2 a aaa}
    {}
    {}
    
  \entry
    {Phone}
    {+00 0000 000000}
    {}
    {}

\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

The output I obtain with this MWE is this one:

[image]

The problem is with the word “phone”, which is not aligned like the rest of the words in its column. I want it to be aligned like the rest of the words in its column. I have thought of different solutions:

1. **Flushing the text right**, but I fear this solution may look ugly because it implies sacrificing the justification…
2. **Making sure that each entry in the relevant column always contains at least two words**, such that the intra-word space can always be adjusted to make sure the content of the cell is justified. However, sometimes there exists no alternative wording that makes sense…
3. **Adjust intra-letter spacing**, to make sure that all words in the relevant column are justified regardless of the number of words. It is my understanding that this is a good option if there is not too much space to correct…

I’d like to try option number 3, but I haven’t been able to figure out a way of doing it. **Could anyone please help me implement option 3 (if possible)?** Ideally, David Carlisle’s answer should be kept as the default whenever there are at least two words in the column, and option 3 should only materialise whenever there is a single word in the column.

Since this is a for a CV of mine that I’m updating, I’m happy to hear typographic and stylistic suggestions by those of you with greater LaTex expertise than mine. Feel free to chime in and give me your two cents, even if you cannot help me implement option 3 as I desire.

Thank you all very much in advance for your time.

Comment: no not 3, surely! even with two words and widely spaced justification is _horrible_ and bordering on unreadable.  Adding letterspacing in the one word case would be even worse. Just set it ragged right.

Comment: What would you, then?

Comment: ragged right if you want anyone to read it.

Comment: Okay… I’m trying to get it ragged right, but I’m not getting it. Could you please provide any little clue as to what I need to modify in the code of my MWE to get the text ragged right?

Comment: you have already specifed the first column as `l` so just use that and delete all the code in the first cell and just have  `\newcommand{\entry}[4]{#1&\parbox[t]{10.0.....`