# Need to close paragraph with `\par` to change spacing

Tags: spacing, document-classes

I have defined a simple class

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mycustom}[2019/03/06 My custom class]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{setspace}

\newcommand{\summary}{
    \begingroup
    \setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
    \onehalfspacing
}

\newcommand{\ensummary}{
    \endgroup
}

\endinput
```

Given that I created a simple LaTeX file, defined as:

```
\documentclass{mycustom}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

        \lipsum[1][1-3]

        \summary
        \lipsum[1][1-4]\par
        \ensummary

        \lipsum[1][1-3]

\end{document}
```

I noticed that I do not add the `par` inside the `\summary` the One and Half Spacing just don't work. I would like to know how this behavior occurs, and if there is a way to remove `\par` and keep the same behavior (one and half spacing inside the `\summary`). Any hints for improvement are very welcome.

This is the paragraph when I add `\par`

[image: With par]

This is the paragraph without `\par`

[image: Without par]

Pay attention to the inline spacing in paragraph at the middle.

Comment: Can't get the behavior you are describing... With or without `\par` I get the same output. Also, why not an environment but commands?

Comment: This question may provide some relevant information: [Inconsistent line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36454)

Comment: Nice. Indeed it helped. Adding a `newline` tells to latex that paragraph ended.

Comment: Unfortunately, `\newline` may in some edge cases add an extra (blank) line.  `\par` is less susceptible to that problem, but even that, if preceded by a space, may do the same if the last line is very tight; that can be avoided by inserting `\unskip\par` before `\endgroup` in ghe `\ensummary` definition.  But @koleygr's question, "why not an environment?", is applicable here; that automatically takes care of all these concerns.

Comment: I don't know what a `environment` is. If is better I would gladly learn about.

Comment: You can create an environment with the command `\newenvironment{sumarry}{<place here the \summary content>}{<place here the \ensumarry content>}` ... Forget `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` since an environment is "grouping" its content by default.... and use like `\begin{summary} <content> \end{summary}`

Answer (score 4):

You should end the environment definition with `\par` so that it is in the scope of the linespace change. Conversely you should *start* the environment with `\par` otherwise the preceding text may be affected (try the example below without the first `\par` in the definition).

As noted in comments this should be an environment (latex normally prevents commands being defined with names starting with `\end...`) in which case the explicit `\begingroup` is not needed, also `\newline` never ends a paragraph, it just forces a linebreak.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace,lipsum}

\newenvironment{summary}
{\par\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}\onehalfspacing}
{\par}

\begin{document}

        \lipsum[1][1-3]
        \begin{summary}
        \lipsum[1][1-4]
        \end{summary}

        \lipsum[1][1-3]

\end{document}
```