# Incorrect line spacing when text is in curly braces

Tags: line-spacing, braces

Consider this minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{
    \Huge
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum
}

\Huge
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image: corr]

Notice how the line spacing looks awkwardly small in the upper part, where the text is inside curly braces. Why is this, and what to do about it?

Comment: Add a `\par` before the `}` or the line spacing used will be that of the font size outside of the `{\huge ...}`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Thank you, that worked wonders. Do you also know why it behaves like this?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: I agree that is a duplicate, in the sense that the answer of that question also perfectly answers my question. The question itself, however, is slightly different, since mine does not presume knowledge about `\par`. As such it makes sense to at least leave the question for the future benefit of others. I have no opinion as to whether the answer-section should be closed, as long as the question itself is not deleted.

Comment: @sigvaldm that's how the site works, the questions closed as dup don't go they are just hidden and searches that would end on this page end up on the existing answer

Comment: In short, TeX can only use one setting of line spacing in a paragraph, and the font change command changes the line spacing to that of the font. When you do `text in 12pt {\huge text} and back at 12pt\par` the setting used by TeX is the last one active when `\par` (or a blank line) was found. I linked to that post because barbarabeeton's answer has the solution _and_ a thorough explanation of why this happens. If you oppose that duplicate, then you can use this one, which is really similar to your question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36454/134574