# Inconsistent Line Spacing When Changing the Font Size in a Verse Environment

Tags: spacing, fontsize, verse, center

I have noticed that when I want to change the font size in a `verse` environment from the default, the spacing between the last two lines in a stanza is adversely affected.

For example, in the following code, I have set `\large` as the document default size; however, when I change the default font size to a larger one, say `\Large`, the space between the last two lines in a stanza is increased over that of the others. On the other hand, when I opt for a smaller font size, say `\small`, the opposite happens.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\large

\begin{verse}
\begin{Large}
{\texttt{This is a line in a stanza \\
\hskip 15pt This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza \\
\hskip 15pt This is a line in a stanza.}}
\end{Large}
\end{verse}

\vskip 25pt

\begin{verse}
\begin{small}
{\texttt{This is a line in a stanza \\
\hskip 15pt This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza \\
\hskip 15pt This is a line in a stanza.}}
\end{small}
\end{verse}

\vskip 20pt

\begin{center}
\begin{verse}
\begin{small}
{\texttt{This is a line in a stanza \\
\hskip 15pt This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza \\
\hskip 15pt This is a line in a stanza.}}
\end{small}
\end{verse}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

with output:

[image]

Finally, I would like to be able to center the stanzas, but `\begin{center}` ; `\end{center}` as you can see, doesn't work. Also, trying to force the stanza over to the right with, say, `\hskip 25pt`, doesn't work either.

QUESTION: Does anyone know what is causing the strange spacing behavior previously noted; and, how may one center a stanza in a verse environment?

Thank you.

Comment: simpler just to use `\small` if you use `\begin{small}...\end{small}` leave a blank line before teh end or the font size changes before the paragragraph ends, so you get small text on normal baseline

Comment: duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36454/inconsistent-line-spacing/36459#36459 for example

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you for your comments. Would you know how to center the stanzas?

Comment: you could put them in a minipage and center that or if you want to centre on longest line use a \begin{tabular}{l} rather than verse and center that,

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you. I might try the tabular suggestion; centering the minipage unfortunately centers each line so that the stanza effect is not the same.

Comment: if you have a center outside the minipage and a verse inside the individual lines should not be centred

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you again.

Comment: Take a look at the `verse` package which provides a variety of ways for formatting verses, including centering them.

Comment: @Peter Wilson Yes; thank you. I did discover yesterday that I could manually force a center with, say,  \begin{verse}[#em] ... \end{verse}, but I was unaware that one could center the stanza directly using that package. Thank you for posting your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `\begin{Large} ... \end{Large}` just simmply `\Large` and similarly for your other font size changes. The `verse` package lets you center verses as well as other useful things.

```
% verseprob.tex  SE 587976

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\large

\begin{verse}
%\begin{Large}
\Large
{\texttt{This is a line in a stanza \\
\hskip 15pt This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza \\
\hskip 15pt This is a line in a stanza.}}
%\end{Large}
\end{verse}

\vskip 25pt

\begin{verse}
%\begin{small}
\small
{\texttt{This is a line in a stanza \\
\hskip 15pt This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza \\
\hskip 15pt This is a line in a stanza.}}
%\end{small}
\end{verse}

\vskip 20pt

\begin{center}
\begin{verse}
\begin{small}
{\texttt{This is a line in a stanza \\
\hskip 15pt This is a line in a stanza \\
This is a line in a stanza \\
\hskip 15pt This is a line in a stanza.}}
\end{small}
\end{verse}
\end{center}

%%%% with the verse package
\settowidth{\versewidth}{But now my love is dead}
\poemtitle{Loves's lost}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
\begin{altverse}
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a batchelor's button \\
In Black-eyed Susan's bed.
\end{altverse}
\end{verse} 

\end{document}
```

[image]