# Inconsistent line spacing within a title

Tags: spacing

I want to have a title for frontpage and control the line break manually. When I add `\\` to bring new line, I get extra space between first and second line, but second and last line seems to be fine. Why this happens and how can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \onehalfspacing
  \thispagestyle{empty}

\textsf{\LARGE{what is going on\\why this linespacing?\\why vertical space is so screwed?}}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to end the paragraph before switching back to normalsize. Use `\Large\sffamily ....` (assuming that you are in a center environment).

Comment: also you should remove the `{...}` after `\LARGE` size commands do not take  an argument

Comment: I am actually unable to replicate the problem behavior you've encountered when using the `article` document class and an up-to-date TeX distribution. Do please tell us which document class you employ, which TeX distribution you use, and when you last updated your TeX distribution.

Comment: Please, make a small example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that shows how you're producing the front page. It will be easier to debug and also to give further advice.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, I added the reproduceable code

Comment: @greg please see the update

Comment: In your `MWE`, still the line `\usepackage{setspace}` was missing, and I' added

Comment: Take a look at this question: [Inconsistent line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36454)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked: What is going on, why this linespacing? An answer is here.

Your code is

```
\textsf{\LARGE{what is going on\\why this linespacing?\\why vertical space is so screwed?}}
```

The LaTeX macro `\textsf{parameter}` opens TeX group, selects required font and typesets `parameter`. Then it closes TeX group.

The LaTeX macro `\LARGE` selects required font and sets bigger value to the `\baselineskip` register. Then you have `{` which opens second TeX group, then you have text and then the second TeX group is closed by `}`. If you remove this irrelevant braces pair the result is the same:

```
\textsf{\LARGE what is going on\\why this linespacing?\\why vertical space is so screwed?}
```

Now, why this linespacing? The LaTeX macro `\\` runs `\par` TeX primitive in this context. So, your example is equivalent to:

```
\textsf{\LARGE what is going on\endgraf why this linespacing?\endgraf why vertical space is so screwed?}
```

The first `\endgraf` (i.e. `\par`) creates one-line paragraph. The second `\endgraf` creates second one line paragraph and when it is distributed to the main vertical list, the `\baselineskip` register has bigger value due to `\LARGE` macro. So, these two paragraphs are with bigger line-skip between them.

Next: the third paragraph `why vertical ...` is opened, i.e. the horizontal mode is opened. Then the parameter of `\textsf` is finalized and the `\textsf` macro closes TeX group. This means that `\baselineskip` returns to its previous smaller value which was valid when `\textsf` macro started. Then the empty line after mentioned code is scanned by token-processor and it creates `\par` here. This `\par` finalizes the third paragraph and it is concatenated to previous two to the vertical list, but `\baselineskip` is smaller now, so there is smaller interline-skip.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a trailing `\\`, but there are better ways to accomplish your task.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}

\begin{document}

% set up the front page
\thispagestyle{empty}

%the author
\begin{center}
\sffamily\large

Dumbo

\end{center}

\addvspace{5cm}

\begin{center}
\linespread{1.25} % or \onehalfspacing if you're using setspace
\sffamily\LARGE

what is going on\\
why this linespacing?\\
why vertical space is so screwed?

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be as:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \onehalfspacing
  \thispagestyle{empty}

\LARGE{
\textsf{what is going on\\why this linespacing?\\why vertical
space is so screwed?}\par}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why the brace after `\LARGE`? It's a declaration that doesn't take an argument.

Comment: Better place the `{` before `\LARGE` so as to avoid that it also changes text coming afterwards.